# pass Bitmap from spinner(activity) to CustomView

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, bitmap

I am implenting a few buttons , SPINNER and EditText in layout for my MainActivity , however, I tried several ways to retrieve my Bitmap from spinner(MainActivity class) to CustomView but failed. Please help me out! Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

TextActivity.java

```
  package com.example.textdrawn2;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

    public class TextActivity extends Activity{

TextView tv;
ImageView iv;
EditText et;
Button b;
public static Bitmap bmap;
Paint paint;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text);


    //Initialise editText, textView & Button
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);     
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    //Spinner (getting texts to be displayed inside drop down box)
    Spinner fontspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fonts_spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
         R.array.fonts_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    fontspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Initialise Spinner
    Spinner fonts_sp;
    fonts_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fonts_spinner);
    fonts_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(myListener);



}


OnItemSelectedListener myListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() { 



        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int pos, long id) {

            //Initialise Button, ET and TV
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnText);
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            //iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            //To enable program to switch to a different font
            switch(pos) {

            case 0: // When user select Code 39 font
                    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
                        @Override     
                        public void onClick(View view) {          
                            if (et.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                                //Clear textView
                                tv.setText("");          
                                et.setText("");
                                tv.buildDrawingCache();
                                iv.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());

                            }
                            else { 

                                //To change to Code 39 barCode font
                                Typeface df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                                        "fonts/IDAutomationHC39M_FREE.otf");         
                                TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);         
                                tv1.setTypeface(df);

                                String editTextValue = et.getText().toString();            
                                tv.setText(editTextValue);

                                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                                tv.buildDrawingCache();
                                bmap = tv.getDrawingCache();
                                iv.setImageBitmap(bmap);

                            }          
                        }
                    });
                    break;

            case 1: // When user select Code 128 font

                b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
                    @Override     
                    public void onClick(View view) {          
                        if (et.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                            //Clear textView
                            tv.setText("");          
                            et.setText("");
                            tv.buildDrawingCache();
                            iv.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
                        }
                        else { 

                            //To change to Code 128 barCode font
                            Typeface df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                                    "fonts/code128.ttf");         
                            TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);         
                            tv1.setTypeface(df);

                            String editTextValue = et.getText().toString();            
                            tv.setText(editTextValue);

                            tv.buildDrawingCache();
                            iv.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
                        }          
                    }
                });
                break;

            case 2: // When user select MOLOT font
                    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
                        @Override     
                        public void onClick(View view) {          
                            if (et.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                                //Clear textView
                                tv.setText("");          
                                et.setText("");
                                tv.buildDrawingCache();
                                iv.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());

                            }
                            else { 

                                //To change to Code 39 barCode font
                                Typeface df = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                 
                                        "fonts/Molot.otf");         
                                TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);         
                                tv1.setTypeface(df);

                                String editTextValue = et.getText().toString();            
                                tv.setText(editTextValue);

                                tv.buildDrawingCache();
                                iv.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
                            }          
                        }
                    });
                    break;
```

Text.Java(CustomView)

```
public class Text extends View implements OnTouchListener {

Typeface fonts ;


public Text(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Molot.otf");
    //et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, 0, 100, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    return true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the class that you want to set the `Bitmap` in, needs a method to do so:

```
Bitmap bitmap;

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Comment: so I  add this method into my customview?

Comment: I had put at my customview , but however there's nothing is being drawn. What more do I have to edit my mainActivity?

Comment: your question asked how to pass the `Bitmap` and all you need to do for that is to add this method to your custom view. then call it in the main activity on an instance of this custom view. if you actually want to know how to have it be shown, i suggest you make another question or at least look up some tutorials on this.